# I want to change Javascript Font , Size and to be Bold

Tags: javascript

this is my Javascript code and I want to change the results Font , size and to be Bold. which part of my code should I add them ?

```
<script>
<!--

var today_obj=new Date()
var today_date=today_obj.getDate()

var tips=new Array()

var tiptitle=''


tips[1]='2-1'
tips[2]='1-1'
tips[3]='2-0'
tips[4]='0-1'
tips[5]='3-2'


document.write(tiptitle)
document.write(tips[today_date])

//-->
</script>
```

Comment: "_which part of my code should I add them_" The part where you write to the page. Write some HTML and CSS instead of just your data.

Comment: `document.write`: ouch.

Comment: Google "css", this is very basic.

Comment: what trincot means is that that is not the best way to write to document as it might overwrite elements try element `document.createElement` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some CSS in a span tag.

```js
var tiptitle = "cheeseburger";

document.write('<span style="color:green; font-size: 30px">'+tiptitle+'</span>')
```

Comment: If I want to put the Text in center how should i do it ?

Comment: add [`text-align: center`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp) to the css

Comment: Thanks a lot , You helped me very good , Its so much valuable for me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Include HTML tags between them. like this:

```
document.write('<p class="result">'+ tiptitle +'</p>');
document.write('<p class="result">'+ tips[today_date] +'</p>');
```

And then style them with css. like this:

```
.result{
   font-famiy:Arial;
   font-size:25px;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

There are other ways too using querySelectors. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp